# Fenchel dual $f^*$ calculated in the gradient $\nabla f$

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ and convex function such that $\nabla f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is bijective.

Is there anything we can say (possibly adding some reasonable hypothesis on $f$) about the following composition?

$$f^*\circ\nabla f$$

(where $f^*$ is the Fenchel conjugate).

I was thinking about something like

$f^*(\nabla f(x)) = f(x)$

but I know in general this is not the case. Does my intuition gets something right, anyway?

Comment: Sorry @dohmatob maybe you read $\nabla f^* \nabla f$ instead of $f^* \nabla f$? Cause that seems the case to me

Comment: Yes, indeed. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
f(x) + f^*(y) = x^\top y
$$
if (and only if) $y = \nabla f(x)$.
Thus,
$$
f^*(\nabla f(x))
=
x^\top \nabla f(x) - f(x).$$

Comment: Thanks! I vaguely remembered some introductory and intuitive explanation of the Fenchel conjugate as being a sort of "change of variables" of the function (probably was this video https://youtu.be/vgLq90cOI_M) and you helped me out :)

Comment: Do you know if we have an analogous result for $f$ just convex?

Comment: Yes, but you have to replace $\nabla f$ by the subdifferential $\partial f$.

Comment: Thank you. So it reads $f(x)+f^*(y)=\langle x, y \rangle \iff y\in\partial f(x) $? Cause this seems too nice to be true to me.

Comment: Yes,    exactly...